# RxSwift: How to respond to a series of notifications?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Suppose I have two notifications coming one after another. I need to wait for work to complete from 1st notification and only then fire the work from 2nd notification. For now, I tried to schedule sequences to a serial scheduler, but it doesn't work as expected, it seems that I'm missing something.

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(.notification1)
  .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
  .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
     self?.doSomeAsynchWork() //Fires another subscription, kind of ugly
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)


NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(.notification2)
  .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
  .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
     self?.doSomeWork() //This should only be executed after doSomeAsynchWork() is done
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I was expecting work to be done in a serial manner, but that's not the case, my guess is that `doSomeAsynchWork()` is, well, asynchronous and `doSomeWork()` fires right after. But can I somehow wait for asynchronous work to complete? Any help is appreciated

UPD: notification2 may or may not arrive, so they are kind of independent of each other. Also, notification1 may or may not arrive, it's just different use cases in the app. But when both notification1 and notification2 are present, I need to wait for `doSomeAsynchWork()` to finish

The flow is as follows:

1. User taps to block some element in the list, which is only allowed for a signed-in user
2. User gets redirected to a sign-in screen
3. User sings in and then, notification1 fires
4. We continue to block that element now that we're signed in
5. Notification2 fires

The problem is when notification1 fired, we need to reload the screen, so that logic comes to doSomeAsynchWork(). On top of that, we're getting the "delete element" notification and we're trying to locate the element which is not there yet, so we're kind of stuck with an inconsistent state, where the element's blocked, but still present on a screen

The difficulty is that we can sign-in without blocking element and we can block element without the need of signing-in in (because we are already signed-in for example)

Comment: I’m confused, are there two signals or three? Sounds like 3: notif1, notif2, and signal emitted to report completion of `doSomeAsynchWork`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. 3 signals, but a lot of side effects are hidden in doSomeAsynchWork

Comment: Ok but if there are three distinct signals to wait for then that is the flaw with your code, it is only waiting for two of them. Or perhaps I don’t know what you mean by side effects. If doSomeAsynchWork kicks off multiple further async tasks then those are _all_ signals you have to wait for. Please try to rewrite the question more honestly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the flow you described in your update, I would expect to see something like this:

```
func example(tapElement: Observable<ID>, isLoggedIn: Observable<Bool>, presentLogin: Observable<Void>) {
    tapElement
        .withLatestFrom(isLoggedIn) { (id: $0, isLoggedIn: $1) }
        .flatMapFirst { id, isLoggedIn in
            isLoggedIn ? Observable.just(id) : presentLogin.map { id }
        }
        .subscribe(onNext: { id in
            blockElement(id: id)
        })
}
```

I don't see any reason to have all the notifications in the first place.

---

#### Old Answer

I would have `doSomeAsynchWork()` return an `Observable<Void>` which emits an event with the async work is complete. Then I could:

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(.notification1)
    .flatMap { doSomeAsynchWork() }
    .subscribe(onNext: { doSomeWork() }
```

Another option would be to have `doSomeAsynchWork()` return a `Completable`, then you would do something like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(.notification1)
    .flatMap { doSomeAsynchWork() }
    .subscribe(onCompleted: { doSomeWork() }
```

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is I need to only fire doSomeWork() when notification2 arrived, that could or could not happen

Comment: Oh, I thought `doSomeAsynchWork()` fired that second notification...